# Can't capture several groups

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to capture these two as groups: `(.*}` and `[.*]` from this:

```
blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]101111foo
```

so I want `(+){+}`and `[,Tom]` to be a group each.

I tried this:

```
echo "blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]101111foo" | sed -E 's/(\[.*\]) (\(.*})/\2\1---/'
```

But it just outputs the entire line `blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]101111foo` without changing anything, it only works for one group, only when I do `sed -E 's/(\[.*\])/\1---/'` for example, then I can see that it does something:

```
blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]---101111foo
```

But the output I want is this, for several groups:

```
[,Tom](+){+}---blahBLACKtao101111foo
```

Why isn't it making two groups and how can I get the output I want?

**EDIT**: I have to use sed to solve this unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps the `bash` and `shell` tags should be dropped from this, if an acceptable answer can only use `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern does not match because:

- `[,Tom]` comes *after* `(*){*}` in the input, and
- There is no space character in the input text, but there is one in the pattern.

There is no regex syntax for "match A and B in either order", so if you don't know which order they are in, you are going yo have to try both possibilities.

One possible solution would be to first move the bracketed substring to the beginning and then move the other substring:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)(\[.*\])/\2\1/; s/(\[.*\])(.*)(\(.*})/\1\3\2---/'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can think of your input having 5 parts:

> ```
> blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]101111foo
> ^^^^^^^^^      ^^^      ^^^^^^^^^
>     1      2    3    4      5
> ```

And you want to rearrange it like this:

> ```
> [,Tom](+){+}---blahBLACKtao101111foo
> ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
>    4     2         1     3     5
> ```

You can write the capturing groups and rearrange them accordingly:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)(\(.*})(.*)(\[.*\])(.*)/\4\2---\1\3\5/' <<< "blahBLACK(+){+}tao[,Tom]101111foo"
```